# Podio Webform Redirect Not Triggering Analytics Goal

Tags: podio

We set up a webform on our home page with a redirect to a thank-you page with a Google Analytics Goal set up when someone reaches the page. I've tested it and it works if you just go to the page, but the redirect from the webform submission does not trigger the goal.

According to the comment on this forum by a Podio engineer, it should work:
http://www.globimail.com/blog/podio-webforms-and-google-analytics-goals.php

Can someone walk me through the steps of setting up a webform submission to trigger a GA goal/conversion? Am open to other workarounds as well if the redirect does not work.

Answer (score 0):

There is `_gaq` object used, but it is `null` probably because it's not initialized properly.

There is nothing that you need to add to Podio webform. You've re-used code from http://www.globimail.com/blog/podio-webforms-and-google-analytics-goals.php. That code is using object `_gaq`. That object is not initialized. You need to initialize it.

Have a look on https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/ how to init it all.

[image: JS error]

Comment: Hi Pavlo, apologies I'm not sure I understand. Just to clarify, are you saying that a _gaq object should always be triggered for a goal to be recorded, but for some reason it is not triggering when a user accesses the page via the Podio webform redirect? And are you saying that somehow I need to get that _gaq object to trigger? Keep in mind I have not added any special code to the webform other than creating one, setting up a redirect, and embedding it on the site. So I really don't understand what I would need to add to the Podio form.

Comment: there is nothing that you need to add to Podio webform. You've re-used code from http://www.globimail.com/blog/podio-webforms-and-google-analytics-goals.php. That code is using object `_gaq`. That object is not initialized. You need to initialize it.

Comment: I'm actually referring to the comment by Podio engineer Domenico Matteo on that page, which states that the intervention described at the top of the page (which uses the gaq object as you mentioned) is no longer possible or needed because the webpage redirect functionality now exists, meaning goals should now trigger without any extra code. Can you clarify on that?

Comment: So, is your "thank-you" page same page where webform is embeded or different page? Solution posted, is for cases when it's same page. And comment from Domenico was for cases when those 2 pages are different.

Comment: Thank-you page is a different page. So am trying to figure how to get Domenico's solution to work.